# Difference between andhra paatha and dravida patha

Tags: taittirya-upanishad, taittirya-brahmana, taittiriya-aranyaka

Namaste.

I am doing some research on the above topic. Can someone please help me understand the differences/point to any resources ?

In the same context, please throw some light on aryans/dravidians.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, Dravida = below VIndhyas, which includes Andhra, Karnataka, Kerala, TamilNadu

Comment: The Mahanarayana upanishad has a difference between the andhra paatha and dravida paatha. Other upanishads don't.

Comment: Thank you both. Can you also share on why these differences have come up ? Or they just regional traditions or anything more. Also how big are these differences?. Many thanks. Namaste.